# Kubernetes Cron Job to trigger a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, devops

My team to to create a cron in Kubernetes/OpenShift that will trigger our Jenkins pipeline that we have set up. We tried doing the triggers{} syntax and the build periodically option on the Jenkins UI, however these are unreliable for us since whenever Jenkins restarts, those build triggers on Jenkins get removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is two approaches you could use here:

1. Make your Jenkins stateless with the Configuration as Code plugin
2. Use a curlimages/curl container to trigger a job via the Jenkins REST API